# How to list string in class?

Tags: android, list

Hi I will do a program with Android studio and I have `person.class` I try

I want to use the strings in a list.

Example: `Personel.eTC.price.toString()` to

`Personel+ ".eTC."+ .price.toString()` like this

```
public class Personel {
    @SerializedName("BTC")
    @Expose
    public BTC bTC;
    @SerializedName("ETH")
    @Expose
    public ETH eTH;
    @SerializedName("LTC")
    @Expose
    public LTC lTC;
    @SerializedName("DASH")
    @Expose
    public DASH dASH;
    @SerializedName("DOGE")
    @Expose
    public DOGE dOGE;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to list all the field values?

Comment: Post a example to easy understanding about your question

Comment: Please make sure to rephrase your question and what you are trying to achieve since it is really unclear.

Comment: i want to list string name ("bTC", "eTH",... ) in my class(Personel).

Answer (score 0):

i want to list string name ("bTC", "eTH",... )  in my class(Personel). This i use mainactivity page